# Align horizontal RecyclerView items to borders

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

I want my `RecyclerView` items align to screen borders,
`android:layout_width="match_parent"` isn't working and it's giving me this result:

[image]

While this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));`
Here, `numberOfColumns` value would be 2 is you want to show to items at once, equally spaced, in a grid manner.